# Es posible colocar un texto en una posición especifica dentro de un Entry? Python

Tags: python

estuve haciendo una calculadora como un primer proyecto ya que soy nuevo en este lenguaje de programación, y tengo un problema que mas bien es estético en lugar de funcional. Busco que el resultado de una operación aparezca en la esquina inferior derecha. por ejemplo: el resultado de la operación 2+2 en que este caso es 4 se ubique en la esquina inferior derecha como en la imagen, alguna sugerencia seria de ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font
raiz=Tk()
raiz.title("Ventana")
raiz.geometry("500x500+700+200")
raiz.resizable(0,0)
label1=Label(raiz,
            text="CALCULADORA BASICA"+"\n_________________________________________",
            font="arial 10 bold",
            fg="blue",
            )
label1.pack()
entry=ttk.Entry()
display=Entry(raiz,
              font=font.Font(family="times",size=18))
display.pack()
display.place(x=30,y=40,height=100,width=440)
i=0
def numbers(a):
    global i
    display.insert(i,a)
    i+=1
def delete():
    display.delete(0,END)
def deletebyone():
    displayentry=display.get()
    if len(displayentry):
        new_display=displayentry[:-1]
        delete()
        display.insert(0,new_display)

def signos(string):
    global i
    len_operacion=len(string)
    display.insert(i,string)
    i+=len_operacion

def result():
    result=eval(display.get())
    delete()
    display.insert(0,result)

button1=Button(raiz, text=1,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20), command=lambda:numbers(1)).place(x=30, y=310, width=70, height=70)
button2=Button(raiz,text=2,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(2)).place(x=120,y=310,width=70,height=70)
Button3=Button(raiz,text=3,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(3)).place(x=210,y=310,width=70,height=70)
Button4=Button(raiz,text=4,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(4)).place(x=30,y=230,width=70,height=70)
Button5=Button(raiz,text=5,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(5)).place(x=120,y=230,width=70,height=70)
Button6=Button(raiz,text=6,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(6)).place(x=210,y=230,width=70,height=70)
Button7=Button(raiz,text=7,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(7)).place(x=30,y=150,width=70,height=70)
Button8=Button(raiz,text=8,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(8)).place(x=120,y=150,width=70,height=70)
Button9=Button(raiz,text=9,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(9)).place(x=210,y=150,width=70,height=70)
button10=Button(raiz,text=".",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:signos(".")).place(x=210,y=390,width=70,height=70)
button11=Button(raiz,text=0,font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:numbers(0)).place(x=30,y=390,width=160,height=70)
Button12=Button(raiz,text="CE",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:deletebyone()).place(x=320,y=150,width=70,height=70)
Button13=Button(raiz,text="C",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:delete()).place(x=400,y=150,width=70,height=70)
Button14=Button(raiz,text="/",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:signos("/")).place(x=320,y=230,width=70,height=70)
Button15=Button(raiz,text="*",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:signos("*")).place(x=400,y=230,width=70,height=70)
Button16=Button(raiz,text="-",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:signos("-")).place(x=320,y=310,width=70,height=70)
Button17=Button(raiz,text="=",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:result()).place(x=400,y=310,width=70,height=150)
Button18=Button(raiz,text="+",font=font.Font(family="times",size=20),command=lambda:signos("+")).place(x=320,y=390,width=70,height=70)

raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Dos cosas. NUNCA uses eval para evaluar cadenas escritas por el usuario. Imagina que el usuario tipee en tu calculadora un código malicioso y rompa tu programa o haga estragos en la pc.

Comment: Gracias, tendré mucho cuidado ya que vi en un tutorial que lo usaba , buscare alguna alternativa.

Comment: Creo que tu mejor opción, aunque requeriría instalar de más, es sympy. Si tus operaciones son simples, podés hacer un parser simple.  Si son complejas (calculos combinados) y no querés usar modulos de terceros ni recurrir al parser de Python (lo cual requiere un entendimiento más avansado de Python), te tendrías que matar haciendo un parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se puede, la alineación de los entrys aplica a todo el texto. No podés hacerlo por sección.

Pero, hay un hack que se me ocurre:

- Crear dos entrys, uno pegado al otro, sin bordes, en un Frame.
- Alinear el texto del entry de abajo a la derecha.
- Usar padx y pady para crear un espacio alrededor de los Entrys.
- Darle un color de fondo al frame para que los espacios vacíos se rellenen de un color. Este color actuará de color de borde.

**Demo**

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

pantalla_border_color = "gray"

pantalla = tk.Frame(root, bg=pantalla_border_color)

cuenta = tk.Entry(pantalla, bd=0)
cuenta.pack(padx=2, pady=(2, 0))

resultado = tk.Entry(pantalla, bd=0, justify="right")
resultado.pack(pady=(0, 2))

pantalla.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Produce**

[image]

Yo escribí en los entrys para mostrar como se ve esteticamente

**Conclusión**

Esto, solo son dos entrys, no es un "widget personalizado" muy complejo y la mayoría de las complejidades están en aplicar la estetica. Lo que queda es manejar cada entry como se debería (como poner el resultado en el segundo).

**Notas**

- Administrar el ingreso del usuario (por ejemplo, que no pueda escribir en el entry de abajo) es tarea para la casa.
- Esto resultará mejor si lo haces usando una clase derivada de tk.Frame o ttk.Frame. Pero como sos nuevo, usalo así.
- Si vas a usar el ttk, tendrás que aprender a manejar los temas para la parte estetica.

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta. Intentare implementarlo en el código.

Comment: De nada! Que te vaya bien!